# GetVariable from Flash

Tags: vb.net, flash

I'm using the **GetVariable** function to grab a variable from the flash object using Visual Basic, but this is the error I get when it needs to use the **GetVariable** function:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: First guess is that the string you're passing isn't the right one, since the function is setting the fail flag.  Since we don't access to the code it's pretty near impossible to say what the proper string would be.

Comment: The solution is here:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75b4bb7d-8640-4e7d-aed4-25ed8a087f4e/getvariable-from-flash?forum=vblanguage

Answer (score 0):

You have three options here, check for specific misspelled terms and letters. Try to Call GetVariable(). Try and see if the variable is in the _root section of the code.