# How to fix get variables from swf file or flash player in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, actionscript-3, flash

Hi I am a novice programmer I was trying to play a swf file in WinForm and language is C#

```
private AxShockwaveFlash Player;
private void CreatePlayer()
{
    Player = new AxShockwaveFlash();
    Player.Location = new Point(30, 10);
    Player.Size = new Size(1024, 640);
    Controls.Add(Player);
    Player.Menu = false;
    Player.Loop = false;
    Player.WMode = "Direct";
    Player.AllowScriptAccess = "Always";
    Player.Quality2 = "High";
    Player.LoadMovie(0, path);
}
```

here I created my player and I added a simple button and its click event

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(Player.GetVariable("_root.wildPokemon.name"));
    }
        catch(Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
    }
}
```

but when I try to `player.GetVariable("_root.wildPokemon.name")` the variable called `_root.wildPokemon.name`its giving me this error `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.` Is there anything I can do to fix this error? I don't know I gave you guys all information or not about this project of mine. If I missed some information please let me know and here is the action script where I found those variables in the scripts/Frame 3 after decompiling swf file and I don't know is this Action Script 3 or not I think it can be Action Script. [Here](https://jpst.it/18_8D) is the script and I am also giving the swf file [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mBIuuj4FL5w8NEYu2mXQtcXp9xJ9-69F) . One more thing unfortunately I can't edit the swf file coz I want a variable of an online swf game and I can't edit that one. The swf file requires or uses http connection at port 8080 and another one at port 9339. And because of that it becomes a problem coz without the websites swf I can't login [here](http://pokemon-planet.com/game547.swf) is the link which I used as movie but it looks like it is encrypted or something.

Comment: Read this in full, you have to use FSCommand: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75b4bb7d-8640-4e7d-aed4-25ed8a087f4e/getvariable-from-flash?forum=vblanguage, also this is an unanswered duplicate in VB.Net: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20563421/495455 please post your answer when you get it working!

Comment: @JeremyThompson But Unfortunately I can't edit the swf file coz I want a variable of an online swf game and I can't edit that one. The swf file requires or uses http connection at port 8080 and another one at port 9339. And the because  of that it becomes a problem coz without the websites swf I can't login [here](http://pokemon-planet.com/game547.swf "The game online swf file") is the link which I used.

Comment: So, basically, you are trying to hack someone's else game.

Comment: @Organis no i want to run that on winform.But it giving me the http connection error and the variable is an example and I think the swf file gets user id from the webpage and uses in a variable for the user id idk much about it.